# Error bars created using stat_summary don't show in the output graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, errorbar

I’m trying to display error bars (using `stat_summary()`) on a bar chart (using `geom_bar()`). The data file I’m using is just a list of twelve experimental conditions with twelve mean values (12 obs. of 2 variables). The code I’m using is as follows:

```
lowcpdbaravd <- ggplot(data=basemeansAVD, aes(Condition, AVDScore, fill=as.factor(Condition))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#3399CC", "#3399FF", "#0066CC", "#003366")) +
  stat_summary(data = basemeansAVD,aes(x=Condition, y=AVDScore, fill=as.factor(Condition)), fun=mean_se(), geom="errorbar", width=.1, colour="orange", position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("0.5 cpd + Baseline", "0.5 cpd + 0.5 KHz", "0.5 cpd + 4 KHz", "0.5 cpd + 8 KHz"), labels=c("0", "0.5", "4", "8")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10), breaks=seq(0,10,2), expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "Auditory Stimulus (KHz)", y = "Mean AVD Score")
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I also get an error message which says

```
Error in stats::na.omit(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`
```

when running the code, and the following error message when calling the graph

```
No summary function supplied, defaulting to mean_se()

Warning messages:
1: Removed 8 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
2: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

As I say there are 12 observations in the data file, so I’ve produced three graphs each with four variables on the x-axis, and all graphs have the same issue. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you run `dput(basemeansAVD)` and copy the result into your question, that'll help diagnose your issue. Thanks

Comment: The output from dput(basemeansAVD): structure(list(Condition = c("0.5 cpd + 0.5 KHz", "0.5 cpd + 4 KHz", 
"0.5 cpd + 8 KHz", "0.5 cpd + Baseline", "14 cpd + 0.5 KHz", 
"14 cpd + 4 KHz", "14 cpd + 8 KHz", "14 cpd + Baseline", "3 cpd + 0.5 KHz", 
"3 cpd + 4 KHz", "3 cpd + 8 KHz", "3 cpd + Baseline"), AVDScore = c(5.05909090909091, 
5.96818181818182, 6.20909090909091, 3.38636363636364, 15.6681818181818, 
17.2590909090909, 17.2772727272727, 13.8181818181818, 15.2454545454545, 
17.7318181818182, 17.2363636363636, 14.3818181818182)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

Comment: The dataset that you are plotting does not contain the raw data, just the AVDScore. This [link](https://rpubs.com/nayefahmad/stat-summary) has information for how to produce error bars with `ggplot2`. Some of the code has been deprecated, so you might get a warning message with info for how to update it.